# Why click event handler works on the first page only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors, datatables

In my `"fnInitComplete" : function(oSettings, json)` I have a selector like `$('[id^=f_]').each(function ()`.

Datatables get its data server-side and `"bProcessing":true`

I know that my selectors will work only on the first **page** of my datatable and when I will **change the page** my **functions will not work**.

But what could be a solution to make this work even with ajax async loading. I do not want to give up ajax.

An example:

```
"fnInitComplete" : function(oSettings, json) {
$('[id^=r_]').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        alert('Foo');
        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
}
```

Works only for the first loaded rows datatables. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use on() to bind actions to elements that may not be on the DOM when the binding is done.

```
"fnInitComplete" : function(oSettings, json) {
    $(document).on('click', '[id^=r_]', function () {
        alert('Foo');
        e.preventDefault();
    })
}
```